# Shell script to display the perfect numbers in the given range of numbers

Tags: shell

I am trying to solve the question and I know how to check for a perfect number. The code for which is

```
read no
i=1
ans=0
while  [  $i  -le  `expr  $no  /  2` ]
do
if  [  `expr  $no  %  $i`  -eq  0  ]
then
ans=`expr  $ans  +  $i`
fi
i=`expr  $i  +  1`
done
if  [  $no  -eq  $ans ]
then  echo  $no is perfect
else
echo  $no is not perfect
fi
```

I am not able to understand how do I input range of numbers and check. I believe using until loop would be beneficial but I am not able to understand how?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want a `for` loop, as described in https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs

```sh
for ((no = 1; no < $upper_limit; no++)); do
    ...
done
```